# Show that the sum of the terms of a sequence converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

The sequence is $u_n=(1-a)^n$ with  $0< a < 1$.
This sequence clearly converges to $0$.
How can I demonstrate that the sum of its terms converges?
Thank you.

Comment: Well if $a=-1/2$, the sequence diverges. Actually this is true for any $-1 < a <0$. Are you sure about the condition on $a$, especially on the absolute value ?

Comment: For $a=-1/2$ the sequence obviously goes to infinity. Do you mean $0\leq a<1$?

Comment: Since you have |a| <1, a is allowed to be negative. In this case your sequence does not converge to 0.

Comment: I'll edit this. a is positive.

Comment: You can try the ratio test to show convergence or divergence

Answer (score 0):

Let $b:=1-a$. What can you say about $(1-b)*(1+b+b^2+\ldots +b^n)$? Hint: Multiply out.

Then observe that $b^n$ goes to $0$ if $n$ goes to infinity. Finally you get  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} u_n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b^n=?$